# Will Resetting my Router, Bring back its original firmware

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have a Cisco Router with the Type Linksys E4200

I currently have DD-WRT Firmware installed on it, instead of the original firmware that came with the router.

If I do a reset to the router (via the red reset button on the back), will the original firmware comeback or will the DD-WRT Firmware stay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned on the [dd-wrt wiki](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Factory_Defaults):

> ### Resetting to Factory Defaults
>
> **NOTE**: This will not restore firmware to a previous state, it *only
> clears the setting*s.

So no, the firmware will not be replaced unless you replace the firmware.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry no.

You will just get a reset default state of DD-WRT